# Copying Pivot table and Editing

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating and then copying the pivot table and trying to insert pagefieled in second pivot but only the first pivot is being edited instead of second one

Please suggest where I'm wrong

below is the code what i wrote

```
Sub CreatingPivotTable()
    Dim DataRange As String
    Dim DestiRange As String
    DataRange = ActiveSheet.name & "!" & Selection.Address(, , xlR1C1)
    Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.name)
    ActiveSheet.name = "Pivot Table"
    Set PT = ActiveSheet
    Range("a3").Select
    DestiRange = "'" & ActiveSheet.name & "'" & "!" & ActiveCell.Address(, , xlR1C1)
    Worksheets("Data Set2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=DataRange, _
        TableDestination:=DestiRange
    Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    With PvtTbl
        With .PivotFields("Region")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Department")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
         .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Sales"), "Sum of Sales", xlSum
         .PivotFields("Sales").NumberFormat = "#,##.00000"
    End With
    With PvtTbl
     For Each pvtFld In .PivotFields
     pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = True
     pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = False
    Next pvtFld
    End With
    With PvtTbl
        .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium17"
        .PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    Range("f3").PasteSpecial
    Set PvtTbl = Nothing
    Set PvtTb2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
    With PvtTb2
       With .PivotFields("Employee Name")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
       End With
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code when you want to copy a pivot table.

```
With PvtTbl
        .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium17"
        .TableRange1.Select
End With
```

.PivotSelect only selects a specified part of a Pivot Table.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I just crash landed on an answer

just named the new pivot table instead calling it by it's index number and now i can edit the new pivot

```
 Sub CreatingPivotTable()
Dim DataRange As String
Dim DestiRange As String
Dim Inputsheet As Object, PT As Object
Set Inputsheet = ActiveSheet
DataRange = ActiveSheet.name & "!" & Selection.Address(, , xlR1C1)
Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.name)
ActiveSheet.name = "Pivot Table"
Set PT = ActiveSheet
Range("a3").Select
DestiRange = "'" & ActiveSheet.name & "'" & "!" & ActiveCell.Address(, , xlR1C1)
Worksheets("Data Set2").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=DataRange, _
    TableDestination:=DestiRange
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
With PvtTbl
    With .PivotFields("Region")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Department")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
     .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Sales"), "Sum of Sales", xlSum
     .PivotFields("Sales").NumberFormat = "#,##.00000"
End With
With PvtTbl
 For Each pvtFld In .PivotFields
 pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = True
 pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = False
Next pvtFld
End With
With PvtTbl
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium17"
End With

Set PvtTbl = Nothing

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Second Pivot
Inputsheet.Select
DataRange = ActiveSheet.name & "!" & Selection.Address(, , xlR1C1)
PT.Select
Range("f3").Select
DestiRange = "'" & ActiveSheet.name & "'" & "!" & ActiveCell.Address(, , xlR1C1)
Inputsheet.Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=DataRange, _
    TableDestination:=DestiRange, TableName:="New Pivot Man"
Set PvtTb2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("New Pivot Man")
With PvtTb2
    With .PivotFields("Region")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Department")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Employee Name")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
     .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2).PivotFields("Sales"), "Sum of Sales", xlSum
     .PivotFields("Sales").NumberFormat = "#,##.00000"
End With
With PvtTb2
 For Each pvtFld In .PivotFields
 pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = True
 pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = False
Next pvtFld
End With
With PvtTb2
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium17"
End With
End Sub
```